# How to find common subgraph using igraph

Tags: graph, igraph, isomorphism

Given two graph, how can I find the subgraphs in these two graphs that are isomorphic. Currently, I just find igraph has implemented igraph_subisomorphic_vf2, which has two graphs G and H as input and determines whether G contains a subgraph that is isomorphic to H.

Since I haven't found any other function in igraph that can directly solve my problem, I currently think that one way is to enumerate all possible subgraph from a given graph and then use the function igraph_subisomorphic_vf2 to determine whether the subgraph is isomorphic to the other given graph.

For the graphs in my dataset, the average number of nodes is 40. I wonder whether it is a feasible way to solve the problem?

Is there any better way to find maximum subgraph in the given two or more graphs?

Thank you!

Comment: You can create the modular product of the graphs, and then look for the largest clique. Search for 'maximum common subgraph'.